# Close all HTML unclosed IMG tags

Tags: regex, xhtml

Is it possible to do a regex replace on all IMG tags that are unclosed?  If so, how would I identify:

```
  <img src="..." alt="...">
```

...as a potential canidate to be replaced?

```
   = <img src="..." alt="..."/>
```

Update:  We have hundreds of pages, and thousands of image tags, all must of which must be closed.  I'm not stuck on RegEx -- any other method, aside from manually updating all IMG tags, would suffice.

Comment: very good question indeed +1 !

Comment: Looks like he was using HTML and has to switch to XHTML, doesn't it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
(<img[^>]+)(?<!/)>
```

will match an `img` tag that is not properly closed. It requires that the regex flavor you're using supports lookbehind (which Ruby and JavaScript don't but most others do). Backreference no. 1 will contain the match, so if you search for this regex and replace by `\1/>` you should be good to go.

If you need to account for the possibility of `>` inside attributes, you could use

```
(<img("[^"]*"|[^>])+)(?<!/)>
```

This will match, e.g.,

```
<img src="image.gif" alt="hey, look--->">
<img src="image/image.gif">
```

and leave

```
<img src="image/image.gif" />
```

alone.

Comment: Does this assume the `img` element occupies a single text line?

Comment: It does however assume that the alt and title text do not contain a `>`. (Which you are not guaranteed, with hundreds of pages of code).

Comment: You're right. That's one of the reasons why regexes are not the best tool to handle HTML, to paraphrase bobince's legendary post. Of course, you can account for that (will edit my post).

Comment: `<` is not allowed in an attribute value in plain.

Comment: @David Dorward: I’m not quite sure about SGML, but in XML a plain `<` is not allowed.

Comment: how can I do it in javascript regex?

Comment: @Odelya: You can't, at least not with this regex. JavaScript doesn't support lookbehind assertions which this regex relies upon. You could open a new question to see if there's a way to do this in JavaScript.

Comment: @TimPietzcker what about cases where the end tag is right after the image ? e.g. <img src=""></img> how can I exclude these cases?

Comment: @Odelya: `</img>` never existed (legally). If you do find them in an HTML file, just remove them (no need for regex).

Comment: @TimPietzcker  - what if I want to to apply it either to img or to link tag? I tried to do (<img|link[^>]+)(?<!/)> but it wouldn't work

Comment: @Odelya: The comments are not a suitable place for questions like this. You should write a new question with your exact problem instead - that's what StackOverflow is for in the first place.

Comment: done http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111154/close-all-html-tags-not-only-img

Answer (score 3):

In HTML the end tag for an `<img>` "must be omitted", so the start tag closes the element and you can't have an unclosed img.

If you want to convert your HTML to XHTML then use a real parser. Regular Expressions aren't a very good tool for this job.

Comment: @Odelya — When I said "use a real parser" I meant an HTML parser, not an XML parser. Since HTML isn't XML this seemed obvious.

Answer (score 1):

To replace all unclosed IMG tags :

```
content = "text<img src='img.jpg'>text<img src='img.png' >text"
content = re.sub('(<img.*?)>', r'\1/>', content, count=0)
print(content)
```

lookbehind is cool though

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by "unclosed"?

```
 <img src="a1.jpg    <--no ending quotes and end parens
 <img src="a1.jpg"   <-- no end parens
 <img src="a1.jpg">  <-- the tag does not self-close as should be done in XHTML
```

You can *try* to intelligently find such suspects, but you are never guaranteed to be fool-proof.

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried this but a closed img tag is a tag beginning with `<img` with stuffs in and a `/>` at the end.

Here is something I tried in perl

```
!/usr/bin/env perl

my @images = ('<img src="toto.jpg">',
          '<img src="truc/machin.jpg" title="pouet" >',
          '<img        src="pouet.jpg" alt="toto" />',
          '<img src="math/a-greater-than-b.png" alt="a > b">');

foreach (@images) {
    if (/<img\s+(([a-z]+=".*?")+\s*)>/) {
    print "Match : <img $1 />\n";
    }
}
```

Produces:

```
Match : <img src="toto.jpg" />
Match : <img src="truc/machin.jpg" title="pouet"  />
Match : <img src="math/a-greater-than-b.png" alt="a > b" />
```

Comment: And it breaks if attribute values aren't quoted (valid!) or are quoted with single quotes (valid!) or the attribute name contains non-alpha numeric characters (HTML5's data-foo) or if the attribute name includes uppercase characters.

Comment: uppercase is easy to deal with. I tought simple-quotes were not allowed, but it's not the case.
Again, easy to replace: replace " by ['"] but you're right for non-alpha chars. Again, I thing it can be done, but the spec has to be more precise.

Nevertheless, it's possible to achieve this task automaticaly, but  (maybe) not with regexp only. regexp are just a pretty good first filter. I may be enough if the url scheme is always the same on his pages.
Thans for your comment anyway.

Comment: Replacing `"` with  `["']` would cause it to break for `foo="bar 'baz' bar"`. HTML is **not** simple to parse with regex.