# Replace not self-closed br or img tags in nodejs

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

The problem is the same as in [Close all HTML unclosed IMG tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433809/close-all-html-unclosed-img-tags), but the provided regexp `(<img[^>]+)(?<!/)>` requires lookbehind support - which nodejs does not have.

How can I achieve the same result in nodejs?

The source HTML is generated by another application.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? `<img>` and `<br>` tags don't need to be closed, and the self-closing syntax is completely ignored in HTML documents anyway.

Comment: if you are using JSX syntax extension you need to close both img and br.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the regex a bit:

```
/(<img[^>]*[^\/>])>/
```

Or another way (most likely slower):

```
/(<img(?:(?!\/>)[^>])+)>/
```

I tried not to change the assumption of at least 1 character to `>`, i.e. `<img>` will not be matched by your regex `/(<img[^>]+)(?<!\/)>/`, nor the regexes that I suggested above.

If you want `<img>` to be matched by the regex (so that you can modify it):

```
/(<img(?:[^>]*[^\/>])?)>/
```

Comment: Uh, your first regex is much better than mine… +1

Comment: great! the first one is good enough! just it does not match correctly tags without ending whitespaces, such as <img> - but I'm not even sure they are actually valid anyway...!

Comment: @Roberto: You can fix that with `/(<img(?:[^>]*[^\/>])?)>/`

Answer (score 2):

You can restructure that regular expression to one that matches the same but does not use lookbehind:

```
/(<img(?:[^>\/]|\/(?!>))+)>/
```

<sub>However, notice that this is a near duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/1048572) whose answer you should engrain :-)</sub>